# Interpreting a route that does not specify a gateway

Tags: routing, linux-networking

The following line is part of the output of `ip route show`

`10.244.0.0/24 dev kube-bridge proto kernel scope link src 10.244.0.1`

The above route has no gateway specified. Does this mean all it does is specify what interface to use and what source to log for the next package hop directly to the destination? Concretely, what does specifying an interface for the route in this way do at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Concretely, what does specifying an interface for the route in this way do at all?

That is called a "device route", and it means "network 10.244.0.0/24 is directly connected to device `kube-bridge`". Traffic destined for that network will be sent directly out the named device without being routed through an intermediary system.

You have a device route on your system for every network to which your system is directly connected; for example, my local system is connected to my home network (192.168.1.0/24) and to several virtual networks (for containers and virtual machines) via bridge devices. My main route table contains the following device routes, representing the different networks to which my system is attached:

```
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 metric 30
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 metric 427 linkdown
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-a005d70d926e proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 metric 428 linkdown
172.22.0.0/16 dev br-de1557ba233e proto kernel scope link src 172.22.0.1 metric 429 linkdown
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.55 metric 600
192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto static scope link metric 50
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 metric 431 linkdown
```

You may have multiple device routes for the same device if there are multiple address ranges in use on your local network. For example, if I have another device on my home network with address `10.88.0.10`, I can create a device route like this:

```
ip route add 10.88.0.0/24 dev eth0
```

And now even though the only address assigned to my local system is `192.168.1.55`, I can still:

```
$ ping 10.88.0.10
PING 10.88.0.10 (10.88.0.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.88.0.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.867 ms
64 bytes from 10.88.0.10: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.05 ms
```